# Scala Akka Consumer/Producer: Return Value

Tags: scala, akka

### Problem Statement

Assume I have a file with sentences that is processed line by line. In my case, I need to extract Named Entities (Persons, Organizations, ...) from these lines. Unfortunately, the tagger is quite slow. Therefore, I decided to parallelize the computation, such that lines could be processed independent from each other and the result is collected in a central location.

### Current Approach

My current approach comprises the usage of a single producer multiple consumer concept. However, I'm relative new to Akka, but I think my problem description fits well into its capabilities. Let me show you some code:

#### Producer

The `Producer` reads the file line by line and sends it to the `Consumer`. If it reaches the total line limit, it propagates the result back to `WordCount`.

```
class Producer(consumers: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var master: Option[ActorRef] = None

  var result = immutable.List[String]()
  var totalLines = 0
  var linesProcessed = 0


  override def receive = {
    case StartProcessing() => {
      master = Some(sender)

      Source.fromFile("sent.txt", "utf-8").getLines.foreach { line =>
        consumers ! Sentence(line)
        totalLines += 1
      }

      context.stop(self)
    }

    case SentenceProcessed(list) => {
      linesProcessed += 1
      result :::= list
      //If we are done, we can propagate the result to the creator
      if (linesProcessed == totalLines) {
        master.map(_ ! result)
      }
    }

    case _ => log.error("message not recognized")
  }
}
```

#### Consumer

```
class Consumer extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def tokenize(line: String): Seq[String] = {
    line.split(" ").map(_.toLowerCase)
  }

  override def receive = {
    case Sentence(sent) => {
      //Assume: This is representative for the extensive computation method 
      val tokens = tokenize(sent)

      sender() ! SentenceProcessed(tokens.toList)
  }

    case _ => log.error("message not recognized")
  }
}
```

#### WordCount (Master)

```
class WordCount extends Actor {

  val consumers = context.actorOf(Props[Consumer].
    withRouter(FromConfig()).
    withDispatcher("consumer-dispatcher"), "consumers")
  val producer = context.actorOf(Props(new Producer(consumers)), "producer")

  context.watch(consumers)
  context.watch(producer)

  def receive = {
    case Terminated(`producer`) => consumers ! Broadcast(PoisonPill)
    case Terminated(`consumers`) => context.system.shutdown
  }
}

object WordCount {

  def getActor() = new WordCount

  def getConfig(routerType: String, dispatcherType: String)(numConsumers: Int) = s"""
      akka.actor.deployment {
        /WordCount/consumers {
          router = $routerType
          nr-of-instances = $numConsumers
          dispatcher = consumer-dispatcher
        }
      }
      consumer-dispatcher {
        type = $dispatcherType
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
      }"""
}
```

The `WordCount` actor is responsible for creating the other actors. When the `Consumer` is finished the `Producer` sends a message with all tokens. But, how to propagate the message again and also accept and wait for it? The architecture with the third `WordCount` actor might be wrong.

#### Main Routine

```
case class Run(name: String, actor: () => Actor, config: (Int) => String)

object Main extends App {

  val run = Run("push_implementation", WordCount.getActor _, WordCount.getConfig("balancing-pool", "Dispatcher") _)

  def execute(run: Run, numConsumers: Int) = {

    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(run.config(numConsumers))

    val system = ActorSystem("Counting", ConfigFactory.load(config))
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    system.actorOf(Props(run.actor()), "WordCount")
    /*
          How to get the result here?!
    */
    system.awaitTermination

    System.currentTimeMillis - startTime
  }


   execute(run, 4)
}
```

#### Problem

As you see, the actual problem is to propagate the result back to the `Main` routine. Can you tell me how to do this in a proper way? The question is also how to wait for the result until the consumers are finished? I had a brief look into the Akka `Future` documentation section, but the whole system is a little bit overwhelming for beginners. Something like `var future = message ? actor` seems suitable. Not sure, how to do this. Also using the `WordCount` actor causes additional complexity. Maybe it is possible to come up with a solution that doesn't need this actor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the Akka [Aggregator Pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/aggregator.html).  That takes care of the low-level primitives (watching actors, poison pill, etc).  You can focus on managing state.

Your call to `system.actorOf()` returns an `ActorRef`, but you're not using it.  You should ask that actor for results.  Something like this:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val wCount = system.actorOf(Props(run.actor()), "WordCount")
val answer = Await.result(wCount ? "sent.txt", timeout.duration)
```

This means your `WordCount` class needs a `receive` method that accepts a `String` message.  That section of code should aggregate the results and tell the `sender()`, like this:

```
class WordCount extends Actor {
    def receive: Receive = {
        case filename: String =>
            // do all of your code here, using filename
            sender() ! results
    }
}
```

Also, rather than blocking on the results with `Await` above, you can apply some techniques for handling [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.5/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried to understand and use the aggregator pattern you suggested. Find the gist here [link](https://gist.github.com/Tooa/fb650d90cc06bfdb517c). However, to get it work I was forced to use the PoisenPill again. Otherwise, I receive a "dead letters encountered" exception. You're welcome to propose improvements. Some parts of the pattern are also unclear to me (Timeout?). It seems, that these examples are not complete at all. For example is the Aggregator trait extension missing.

Comment: It seems that my result is not deterministic. Today I receive the "dead letters excountered" exception.

Comment: `import akka.pattern.ask; import akka.util.Timeout`